# ODBC stored procedure with php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I simply want to execute a MySQL stored procedure. But I want to use the parameter parsing technique for all the usual reasons. So I've taken the example from the php manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and now have this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL update_bug_status(?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $bug_id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $bug_status);
$stmt->execute();
```

The missing piece of the puzzle is the $dbh variable, which the manual seems to forget to mention!

I thought for $dbh I could use an ODBC connection variable like this:

```
$connection_string = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=10.32.27.6;Database=bugs";
$dbh=odbc_connect($connection_string,'root','xxxxxx');
```

But this doesn't work because 'odbc_connect' simply returns an id number.

I've seen other examples that seem to make use of mysql specific functions. But I don't have these functions available so I want an answer that uses standard ODBC functions if possible.

Comment: Your link is broken, but I suspect you are using a PDO method on an ODBC connection, and you should use [`odbc_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) and [`odbc_execute`](http://php.net/odbc_execute).

Comment: @Wrikken You should submit that as an answer because that looks like exactly what is going on.

Comment: Was waiting for the actual link to be sure, but upgraded it to an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a PDO method on an ODBC connection (see the menu on the left to see which portion of the manual you are in), and you should use [`odbc_prepare`](http://php.net/odbc_prepare) and [`odbc_execute`](http://php.net/odbc_execute) (either that, or rather then doing an `odbc_connect` use the `PDO` driver).